# How should I address a recruiter using the wrong name?

Tags: software-industry, job-offer, name

A recruiter emailed me today with a quick update about finalizing my offer. My friend is in the same process and received the same email.

Unfortunately, the recruiter did not bother to change the names when copy pasting the email he sent to my friend to me. Our names are completely different, so this is clearly just a copy-paste issue and not a matter of mixing us up.

Would it be best to ignore the mistake in my response, or politely correct him? If I should correct him, what would be the best way to do that without causing offense? I don't want to mess anything up at this point.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't make a big deal about it, but do correct him.  Depending on your email address, he could have you both mixed up more permanently, and you don't want to be getting each others' offers or visas, do you?

Just reply and say "Quick question, your last email said Joe Blow - was that intended for me or was it mis-sent?  I'm hoping it was really for me because I'm looking forward to moving ahead in the process." Or similar based on the content of the email.

Comment: Did something along the lines of this yesterday and he got back to me - he apologized and confirmed that the email was for me as well. I was definitely overthinking it, thank you for your help.

Comment: Great!  Professionally clarifying is always good.  Being assertive enough to clarify ambiguity and error is a very important skill and will help you in many ways in your career.

Answer (score 6):

Just ignore it.   In the end, the recruiter is more interested in matching you with a job than getting a name correct.

But think about this...it's also an indication of the fact that getting an email from a recruiter in and of itself doesn't mean one is particularly gifted or qualified.   That recruiter was likely doing a scattergun approach and emailing dozens of potential targets hoping to hit one that wanted help.

But that's ok -- use the recruiter to further your cause.    If they have a job to set you up in, go for it.   It's then between you and that employer, and the recruiter ceases being relevant after your first interview with the potential employer.

Comment: This is just an update on the visa process before getting a formal offer letter. I've already gone through most of the hiring process.

Comment: AH...I see.   Again...I wouldn't worry about it.  The recruiter is just the middle-man, right?